# equivalence of contentPlaceHolder in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using PHP and CodeIgniter. In every view file, I include the `header.php`, seen below:

```
<head>
  <link rel="...">
  <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
</head>
```

Notice that the head tag is closed in this file. Now I want to add a `<script>` tag in another file without modifying `header.php`. C# has `ContentPlaceHolder` that can be used to indicate where tags can be added within head tag. Is there any equivalent in php? If not, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add other scripts in your header by adding a single variable in your controller like this:

Controller:

```
$data['myScript'] = '<link rel="..."><script type="text/javascript">...</script>';
$this->load->view('myView',$data);
```

Then in your header.php add:

```
<head>
  <link rel="...">
  <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
  <?php if (isset($myScript)) echo $myScript; ?>
</head>
```

This makes a very customizeable template for each view because you can add the scripts only in the views you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I usually do with any CodeIgniter project...

I extend the HTML helper (`application/helpers/MY_html_helper.php`) to include a `js()` function:

```
function js($js)
{
    $js_base_path = '';

    // If you have multiple JS files, pass an array
    if(is_array($js))
    {
        foreach($js as $script_src)
        {
            if(strpos($script_src, 'http://') === false && strpos($script_src, 'https://') === false)
            {
                $js_base_path = base_url() . 'js/';
            }
            echo '<script src="' . $js_base_path . $script_src . '"></script>';
        }
    }

    // Otherwise, a string will do
    else
    {
        if(strpos($js, 'http://') === false && strpos($js, 'https://') === false)
        {
            $js_base_path = base_url() . 'js/';
        }
        echo '<script src="' . $js_base_path . $js . '"></script>';
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'll include my [footer](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/) (header, in your case) with a `js` parameter:

```
$this->load->view('_footer', array('js'=>'jquery.cycle.lite.js'));
```

My `_footer` view runs the `js()` function like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($js))
{
    $this->load->helper('html');
    js($js);
}
?>
```

---

This has worked great for me, feel free to customize it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Phil Sturgeon's template library has some handy functionalities for this:
http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/library.html#prepend_metadata